# Can I see a list of removed questions?

Tags: discussion

I see the bottom of vote list good and some good questions removed cuz of low votes. Is there way to see the removed or I have to go through all possible question id?

Comment: If they were deleted because they had negative votes, then they probably weren't good questions...

Comment: @JoKing Besides some off topic but good questions, some are downvoted cuz some user don't know or refuse to admit knowing its base

Answer (score 2):

### Nope

With [2,000 rep](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) (Or eventually 10K once our privilege levels are adjusted), you can see deleted posts. But you can only see them if you have the link to them. There is no way for normal users to see a list of deleted questions, or to search for deleted questions.

Note that you can use the [`deleted:1` search operator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145060/enable-searching-with-deleted1-for-10k-users), but this will only show you your own posts.

Comment: It's not a huge project to scan through all possible Qs, but that'd be a lose-lose

Comment: @l4m2, you can use data.stackexchange.com to identify undeleted post IDs efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

With 2000 reps you may see others' removed posts up to 30 days [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last30days), in the "Recent occurrences" - "Recently Deleted" part. But it doesn't seem to cover self deletes.